# How do I make this code reusable on different views? Proper method

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am somewhat confused on the proper way to perform the following. Is this a class a function or an object? (Not sure) So here goes (please be kind) I'm learning codeigniter/php simultaneously.

```
    $is_live = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $is_live = ucwords($is_live);
            if (!$is_live == null)
                   echo 'Hello, '.$is_live.
                   ' <b>(Not you? '.'<a href="' .base_url().
                   'main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>';
```

I wrote this code, which checks if a session is set and if true echo the details. I currently have this code on my `view/main` However I want to have this code displayed on all pages.

What is the proper way to do this?

1. Do i create a `view/header` which is auto loaded on each page and insert this `code` there?
2. Do I create a `class/public function` in a `helper` file and load it where needed?
3. Do I create a `class/public function` in a `library` file and load it where needed?
4. Do I create a `public function` in a controller?

-EXTRA-
My assumption is option `1` but I'm curious what if I want to display this information in another location on a particular page? I don't want to have to copy/paste the code block because that is sloppy.

How would I set it up so that I can just call it where i need it? 
e.g. `$this->load->helper('check_for_sess');`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class isLive
{   
    public function is_live() {

        $is_live = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $is_live = ucwords($is_live);
             if (!$is_live == null)
               echo 'Hello, '.$is_live.
               ' <b>(Not you? '.'<a href="' .base_url().'main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>'; 

    }
}
```

On the `view` I tried this:

```
<?php 
    $isLive = new isLive;
    $isLive->is_live(); 
?>
```

This however doesn't work and causes a ' function userdata() on a non-object error '

Can someone please explain the proper way to achieve my desired solution and the correct syntax. Thanks in advance!

-UPDATE-- Tried to create a library - still getting error.

```
#Created a library 
class CheckSess 
{   
    function IsLive() 
    {   
    $is_live = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $is_live = ucwords($is_live);

            if (!$is_live == null) 
            {
               $check_msg = 'Hello, '.$is_live.
               ' <b>(Not you? '.'<a href="' .base_url().'main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>';
            }

    return $check_msg;
    }

}


#In the View
<?php echo $this->CheckSess->IsLive();  ?>

#in the controller
$this->load->library('CheckSess');
```

--UPDATE--

```
class CheckSess {

    function IsLive() 
    {   
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $is_live = $CI->session->userdata('email');
    $is_live = ucwords($is_live);

            if (!$is_live == null) 
            {
               return 'Hello, '.$is_live.
               ' <b>(Not you? '.'<a href="' .base_url().'main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>';
            }

    }

}
```

Set this^ is the `libraries` folder

the `view` shows `<?php echo $this->CheckSess->IsLive(); ?>`

and the `controller` shows `$this->load->library('CheckSess');`

please advise. Thanks again!

ERROR---

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function IsLive() on a non-object in C:\wampserver\www\test-app\application\views\homepage.php on line 56
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0005  151432  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0014  187792  require_once( 'C:\wampserver\www\test-app\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' )    ..\index.php:202
3   0.0277  1537000 call_user_func_array ( )    ..\CodeIgniter.php:359
4   0.0277  1537048 Main->index( )  ..\CodeIgniter.php:359
5   0.0283  1540200 CI_Loader->view( )  ..\main.php:8
6   0.0283  1540640 CI_Loader->_ci_load( )  ..\Loader.php:419
7   0.0287  1566584 include( 'C:\wampserver\www\test-app\application\views\homepage.php' )  ..\Loader.php:833

Comment: You have some unsafe and unstable code there, your `if()` does not have an `else` part, so when your conditional will fail, you will get an error that you are trying to `echo nothing`. At least add `} else { echo ""; }` for the code to work in every situation

Comment: how about else return false? -----ERROR----
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$CheckSess

Filename: views/homepage.php

Line Number: 50

Comment: Do you really want to echo "false" in your view file? Or you should build if-then-else in your view file when calling this method. This error actually states, that there was a problem with loading your library, so you should see if it's in a corresponding folder and all names are correct. Try loading the library this way:
`$this->load->library('CheckSess', '', 'checksess');` and then use it like `$this->checksess->isLive()`

Comment: Yep that worked. - How were you able to decipher that error so quickly. I find the error messages to be somewhat obscure. I followed the naming directions for `libraries` to a T - Not sure why it has to be renamed in the controller like that. Thank You!

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html --> Naming conventions "
    File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php
    Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
    Class names and file names must match.
"

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function IsLive() on a non-object` this line assumes you have no object to call a method from, so it's a loading problem. You can try removing my edit of loading the library and calling `$this->checksess->isLive()` with the library name in lowercase, it should work too

Comment: I think this turned out to be a great question with great answers and detailed commentary explanations --- If i could --- I would vote up the questions --- I think many people code benefit from all the data on this page.

Comment: yes i changed `$this->load->library('CheckSess', '', 'checksess');` to `$this->load->library('checksess');` and correct it does work fine. :)  Actaully now that you bring that up -- what is the middle `''` quotes for?

Comment: I think all of the information here was discussed on SO at least a dozen of times already, it's simply separated in many questions and this is a question about a particular problem

Comment: Either way - great info && succinct answers! Anyways-- Thank you again for all your help -- I learned a lot from this. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best ways to write such reusable in CodeIgniter are Models and Libraries.

With libraries being better because the code and logic you use isn't actually what models in MVC are, but with CodeIgniter and especially for a beginner it's pretty much ok to write this in models if you are not planning to distribute or share this code in any way.

I would suggest reading more on what goes where in CodeIgniter, you can find plenty information here, on SO or on official CI forums, but as a quick reference, I will write a list of what goes where.

### Views

Static, dumb data output, formatting, iteration(for displaying tables, lists, etc.).

The only things you want to use here are some of the basic PHP functions, CodeIgniter helpers, `for`, `foreach`, `while` loops and conditionals (`if`, `case`)

### Controllers

Form data capture and validation, catching data from models, sending data to views, redirects.

### Models

Querying, reading, writing and updating data from databases, remote sources (APIs), files.

### Helpers

Often used functions that are expected to be used in views - formatting HTML, parsing and displaying trees as lists `<ul><li></li></ul>`, shorthand functions for other functions like

```
function mydate() {
    return date("d.m.Y");
}
```

Stuff that does not use any of the CodeIgniter libraries/models (Technically it can use, but should be avoided in most cases).

### Libraries

Custom classes and objects, data processing, API interfaces, complex of the aforementioned

---

---

If you want to display some view file with data, I would put it in a library. You can put it in to a model. In my projects when I use some parts, I have a library/model (difference in our case is minimal), lets call it `pmodel`.

```
class Pmodel extends CI_Model() {
    function ShowHeader() {
        $data = array(
            'user' => $this->usermodel->GetCurrentUser()
        }
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
    }

    function ShowMyPart() {
        $is_live = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $is_live = ucwords($is_live);
        if (!$is_live == null)
               echo 'Hello, '.$is_live.
               ' <b>(Not you? '.'<a href="' .base_url().
               'main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>'; 

    }
}
```

Now anywhere in the view files you can call `$this->pmodel->ShowMyPart()` if you have loaded it before (models of this type should be autoloaded anyway).

There is one little change I would do as it's considered as good practice - never `echo` anything from anywhere but the view files, `return` values instead.

Change the `echo` keyword to `return` and in your view file simply write `echo $this->pmodel->ShowMyPart()`.

Why should you do that? Because, if you would like to call any method that echoes something from the controller right between loading header and footer(eg.), CodeIgniter will echo this before the header as CodeIgniter does not echo your loaded views right away, it saves them to output storage and sends the finalized output right before destructing himself. More reading can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html).

But you can do even better - use a view file to output any data you want, just create a helper and load it from your model/library as you do in your controllers.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT**

For your edited question, the reason why you are getting errors with your library is that your library doesn't know that an instance of CodeIgniter even exists as you are not extending your library from it, as you do with your models and controllers. You don't use `$this` to refer to CodeIgniter classes in your libraries, as `$this` is a reference to your library itself, which is a separate class. To use CodeIgniter classes you should get a CodeIgniter instance:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

And then you can use `$CI` instead of `$this` to call CodeIgniter classes by changing the line:

```
$is_live = $this->session->userdata('email');
```

to

```
$is_live = $CI->session->userdata('email');
```

Comment: Hey I'm very grateful for your reply - I appreciate you taking the time to write such an elaborate response. As you wrote this I updated my question thinking that library was the proper way to go. Please see my revised code and comment as you see fit. Also what do I write in the class? `class CheckSess extends ...` I created the file as dictated by the syntax on creating a proper library (uppercase and matching names) What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a basic html helper and autoload it in the config file.

Then you can make a function for this...

```
function displayLoginStatus($em)
{ 
    $html = '';
    if($em)
    {
        $html = 'Hello, '.ucwords($em).' <b>(Not you? '.'<a href="' .base_url().'main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

then you call it like a normal function:

```
<?php echo displayLoginStatus($this->session->userdata('email')); ?>
```

but ideally you would place something like this in a template or header file that wraps your standard page views. There's no need to make a function out of something like this since typically you don't have the login / logout in multiple places on the page.
It could be condensed simply to:

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('email')): ?>
Hello, <?php echo ucwords($this->session->userdata('email')); ?> <b>(Not you? <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/logout">Log Out</a>) </b>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I prefer to make a site template and wrap the views with it. Makes common elements much easier to handle.
Some people template it this way:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/88335/

There are many ways you could handle this, but the general idea is to separate your most common elements into one template view. I don't know of a succinct way of instructing you on how to do this so I will only update this post if you feel the need for much more explanation on templating.

helper docs:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: Don't forget, that you can't use `$this` in helpers, refer to an edit in my answer to see why

Comment: I appreciate your advice and input. You provided a great example and possible solution. Asking this question I was seeking an "industry standard" kind of answer-- however from both of your replies I feel like the solution is really dependent on the coders' personal preference (as long as organization is maintained consistently) So is it fair to assume that from a performance perspective that either solution would run just as good as the other?  @Vlakarados I tried your updated code modification however I still getting errors. I will update my code -- if you don't mind please review. Thanks

Comment: @fabio I will try to help, but you should include the errors you get themselves as I can't guess what's wrong there =) In any case - yes, this is a matter of preference, we have just provided few of the possibilities that we, to our own experience work better =)

Comment: Keep in mind that while it is always better to have a neat and orderly programming preference, in the end it is not likely any of these methods will hinder performance in a noticeable way. If you get into enterprise level work then it would matter and you would want to be as efficient as possible, but for most sites used by the standard person / client, I wouldn't worry too much about the benchmarks of something like this.