# codeigniter shorten method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor , currently  i have a library named "Common_func" which is autloaded.

and i can call it like this everywhere

```
$this->Common_func->common_method();
```

its ok in case of working with controllers and models , but in case of views it makes the HTML ugly ,

I know about the template parsing options , but i do not want to go with that.

is there any posible way to access with a shorten structure.

like this (or similer with least words)

```
Common_func->common_method();
```

or better than this.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can copy a part to a new variable... **$short = $this->Common_func;** and then call **$short->common_method();**

Comment: He has to do this in every method he wants to use this library, this will make more lengthier

Comment: question : why you need to access the method in the views? it does not sound right (pardon me if i too naive)

Comment: @ajreal it is a common library ,ex. we ported the jQuery Ui lib to CI , so we can easily integrate UI things to our projects ,also this is a `LIBRARY`.

Comment: i think @Vlakarados got the point, see his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is not to use libraries in `View` files at all, libraries are meant to be used in controllers and models. Helpers are used for views, they are random functions that help you with formatting/code generation and sometimes even more.

Nevertheless, if you really want to keep your library and it's methods you can make "abstract" helpers, that will help you with making view files clean and readable:

**common_helper.php**

```
function common_method($arg) {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    return $ci->Common_func->common_method($arg);
}
```

That will keep your helpers updated with the changes made in the library.

Comment: I agree with the best practice , but in terms of CI helpers are limited,in some areas our lib have more things to do.

Comment: How are they limited? They are not limited at all and everything library can do, helper can do as well.

Comment: technically agree , but a question then why there is `helper` and `library` ? (i am not arguing , but i just want to learn new things) :D

Comment: I have answered a similar question here, so check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631726/how-do-i-make-this-code-reusable-on-different-views-proper-method/12631941#12631941

Answer (score 0):

I found this in codeigniter forum. This link might help you

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/139788/

or you can shrink a little if your library name is pretty long this way

```
class SomeClass extends CI_Controller{
   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->lib=$this->Really_Long_Library_name;
   }
}
```

this way you can use `$this->lib` to access its methods.